# Alias for Entity Framework Types?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the entity framework model:

```
public class Location
{
    public bool IsCustomer { get; set; }

    public bool IsSupplier { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : Location {}

public class Supplier : Location {}
```

In this situation I want to have `Customer` as an alias. Whenever I get the `DbSet<Customer>` it should return all `Location`s that have `IsCustomer == true`.

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You can use TPH and configure a discriminator.

Comment: how about using directives? For example, `using LocationCustomer = YournameSpace.Location;`

Comment: @AluanHaddad: That doesn't work because Code first mapping (e.g. `m => m.Requires("IsCustomer").HasValue(true)` will cause entity framework to create the column and throw an error because the column exists twice. In my instance I want a fluid type where the user can change `IsCustomer` and query on it.

Comment: @kashi_rock: Can you explain? Not sure how that would solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout following code to use directives instead of using class name itself:

```
using myLocation = mytestApp.Location;

namespace mytestApp
{
    public class Customer : Location 
    {
        private void myMethod()
        {
            myLocation loc = new myLocation();
            loc.IsCustomer = true;
            loc.IsSupplier = false;
        }
    }

    public class Supplier : Location { }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand what you are doing, but how would this accomplish anything? `myMethod` is not a constructor, and entity framework still needs to somehow discriminate between types.

Comment: Its not a constructor but a method which I illustrated to explain how you can use directive myLocation instead of class name Location